# Autotools: Optionally compile and link against a third-party library

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake, libtool, build-system

I have an executable project `prog` on autotools build-system. This program links against `libfoo` which is also an autotools project.

I want to give my users (who wish to compile `prog`) the freedom to choose between linking against a previously installed `libfoo`, or to configure, compile (static linkage) and link to the `libfoo` source tree which is shipped within package (in `third-party` directory)

`libfoo` uses [libtool](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/) and [pkg-config](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) if it matters...

Ideally this would be done with some autoconf arguments:

```
./configure --with-local-libfoo
```

vs

```
./configure --with-system-libfoo
```

The question is how to tell the buildsystem to compile `libfoo` before `prog` (in second case) and how to provide correct link flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since libfoo is also an Autotools project, a copy of which is distributed inside the main project, it would be natural to set it up as a subproject.  The key Autoconf macro here is `AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS`.  Thus, if the libfoo package were in a subdirectory `libfoo/` of the directory containing the top-level `configure` script, the top-level `configure.ac` would use

```
AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS([libfoo])
```

In that case, the top-level configure script will run libfoo's configure script automatically, passing it all the same options it received (including any that are meaningful only to libfoo).  Moreover, the top-level script's `--help` option will print both its own and `libfoo`'s options.  You can make that conditional on a `--with-*` argument (but just one, don't use two different ones).

On the Automake side, look into [Automake conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html#Conditionals) and [conditional subdirectories](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Conditional-Subdirectories.html#Conditional-Subdirectories).  You can use conditionals, with the condition controlled by your `--with-system-libfoo` or whatever, to select the right set of link options and to determine whether `make` will recurse into the libfoo package.  When you're building your own copy of libfoo, it might be helpful to include the `-static-libtool-libs` option among the main program's link flags.

The last bits revolve around preventing the local libfoo, when you build it, from being installed on the system along side the main program.  I haven't come up with a good solution that doesn't involve tweaking libfoo's build system.  Do switch `libfoo.la` to be a convenience library (named in `noinst_LTLIBRARIES` instead of in `lib_LTLIBRARIES` or such) and in fact generally switch build targets in the libfoo subpackage from installed ones to `noinst_` ones.